# php artisan migrate nothing to migrate error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, artisan-migrate

I am trying to install [this package](https://github.com/igaster/laravel_cities) on my server after installing everything when I try to migrate with `php artisan migrate` it tells me there is nothing to migrate. Also the migration table is not there. here is what I did:

1. php composer.phar require igaster/laravel_cities
2. change in providers app.php

   `Igaster\LaravelCities\GeoServiceProvider::class,`

Ran this script

```
mkdir storage/geo
cd storage/geo
wget http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/allCountries.zip && unzip allCountries.zip && rm allCountries.zip
wget http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/hierarchy.zip && unzip hierarchy.zip && rm hierarchy.zip
```

Now when I run `php artisan migrate` it tells me there is **nothing to migrate**

I am not sure if this is because I have `php composer.phar` instead of `composer`?

Comment: @Hina, You should run `composer dump-autoload` and then give `php artisan migrate:refresh` a try. This will remove all current migrations and re migrate them

Comment: @Option the migrate:refresh commands creates all tables except this one, its also not included in the migrations table

Comment: @Hina, I have just edited my comment. Give that a try ^

Comment: @Hina `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Igaster\LaravelCities\GeoServiceProvider"`

Comment: still nothing to migrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Igaster\LaravelCities\GeoServiceProvider"
```

And then run the migration

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: I get this error when running the command [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  Too many arguments, expected arguments "command".

Comment: I miss to add "--" right before provider. Thanks @rbaskam for edit suggestion. Try now

Comment: If it still failling you can publish files "manually" , just copy the files inside `vendor/igaster/laravel_cities/src/migrations`  to your migrations folder

Answer (score 2):

Try `php artisan config:cache` then retype `php artisan migrate` - Hope this helpfull...

Answer (score 0):

php composer.phar is identical to composer so thats not the issue.

If migration file not showing you likely need to run

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Comment: I still get nothing to migrate after running this

Answer (score 0):

Copy `vendor/igaster/laravel_cities/src/migrations` folder contents to `database\migrations` folder, then run `php artisan migrate`. Sometimes publishing vendor resources doesn't work for me too and I dive into the source of the package then to make them work.